# photoswipe won't return to the original page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, photoswipe

I am using photoswipe to show my gallery when clicking on a item.

**My markup**:

```
<ul id="gallery_mobile_about">
        <li>
            <a href="/files/uploads/Detalle-Magrana.jpg" style="background-image: url('/files/uploads/Detalle-Magrana.jpg');" data-iframe="" data-pos="0" data-url="/files/uploads/Detalle-Magrana.jpg" class="gallery-item ui-link"></a>
        </li>
    <li>
            <a href="/files/uploads/Figues-de-Moro.jpg" style="background-image: url('/files/uploads/Figues-de-Moro.jpg');" data-iframe="" data-pos="1" data-url="/files/uploads/Figues-de-Moro.jpg" class="gallery-item ui-link">

            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/files/uploads/Cala-Deià-50x30cm1-1024x782.jpg" style="background-image: url('/files/uploads/Cala-Deià-50x30cm1-1024x782.jpg');" data-iframe="" data-pos="2" data-url="/files/uploads/Cala-Deià-50x30cm1-1024x782.jpg" class="gallery-item ui-link">
            </a>
        </li>
    <li>
            <a href="/files/uploads/Deia-Church-on-Cala-rock.jpg" style="background-image: url('/files/uploads/Deia-Church-on-Cala-rock.jpg');" data-iframe="" data-pos="3" data-url="/files/uploads/Deia-Church-on-Cala-rock.jpg" class="gallery-item ui-link">
            </a>
        </li>
</ul>
```

**The js**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var myPhotoSwipe = $("#gallery_mobile_about a").photoSwipe(
    { enableMouseWheel: false , 
        enableKeyboard: false } 
    );                  
});
```

**The problem** is that even that the gallery seems to load, as a backgound i see a white page with the text 'undefined' and on closing the galler page will stay as this white  page (is not returning to the original view)

**The result** (hit on a image where it says 5 items in gallery): http://deia.info/m/?lan=2&task=view_post&catid=14&blogid=25

What am I seem to be missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `rel="external"` solved this

Answer (score 0):

I allready have the attribute `rel="external"` and trying things this works for me.

> ```
>         var myPhotoSwipe = $("#Gallery a").photoSwipe({
>             //your others attributes
>             target: 'html'
>         });
> ```